# Format Time to HH:mm C# + MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

I want 'Time' to be displayed as HH:mm on UI (editable mode)

my code so far :

```
    [DisplayName("JobProcessEndTime")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Is required field. Format HH:MM (24 hour time)")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan JobProcessEndTime { get; set; }
```

in view

```
 <%-- <td class="data"><%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobProcessEndTime)%></td>--%>
            <td class="data"><%= Html.TextBox("JobProcessEndTime", string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", Model.JobProcessEndTime))%></td>
```

tried both ways in view.  still it displays the 'seconds' part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="data">
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.JobProcessEndTime) %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The format string should be

```
@"{0:hh\:mm}"
```

and either one of the method would work.

Answer (score 0):

To het this to work in MVC 3 I had to use Html.EditorFor instead of Html.TextBoxFor.

```
<td class="data">
    <%= Html.EditorFor(x => x.JobProcessEndTime) %>
</td>
```